# if/else condition for matching a regex in a file

Tags: search, regular-expression, functions

I want to run a function with a condition that checks for ANSI color escape codes when I open files but I don't know how to write the condition.

I expect it to look something like this:

```
if ? '^[[0;32m'
    " stuff to do...
endif
```

(`^[[0;32m` contains a control character instead a literal '^[')

How do I write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `search()` function. Something like this should work:

```
if search('\e\[\d\+;\d\+m', 'nW')>0
```